# C# Bad Performance OData when using extension

Tags: c#, sql-server, odata, webapi, .net-4.8

I have a Web API for OData services. I have a lot of table with many relations. Here is some of the table:

1. MSADDRESSCOUNTRY

```
public partial class MSADDRESSCOUNTRY
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage","CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public MSADDRESSCOUNTRY()
    {
        this.MSADDRESSPROVINCEs = new HashSet<MSADDRESSPROVINCE>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CODE { get; set; }
    public string COUNTRYNAME { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage","CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<MSADDRESSPROVINCE> MSADDRESSPROVINCEs { get; set; }
}
```

2. MSADDRESSPROVINCE

```
public partial class MSADDRESSPROVINCE
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public MSADDRESSPROVINCE()
    {
        this.MSADDRESSDISTRICTs = new HashSet<MSADDRESSDISTRICT>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> COUNTRYID { get; set; }
    public string PROVINCENAME { get; set; }

    public virtual MSADDRESSCOUNTRY MSADDRESSCOUNTRY { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage","CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<MSADDRESSDISTRICT> MSADDRESSDISTRICTs { get; set; }
}
```

3. MSADDRESSDISTRICT

```
public partial class MSADDRESSDISTRICT
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public MSADDRESSDISTRICT()
    {
        this.MSADDRESSSUBDISTRICTs = new HashSet<MSADDRESSSUBDISTRICT>();
    }
    
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PROVINCEID { get; set; }
    public string DISTRICTNAME { get; set; }
    
    public virtual MSADDRESSPROVINCE MSADDRESSPROVINCE { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<MSADDRESSSUBDISTRICT> MSADDRESSSUBDISTRICTs { get; set; }

}
```

I create DTO object model for every table with the property is the same with Database object model.
I want the client can use `$expand` keyword to get child data and/or parent data.

For `MSADDRESSCOUNTRY` I need to write the code like this.

```
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 4)]
public IQueryable<MsAddressCountryObject> Get()
{
    return db.MSADDRESSCOUNTRies.Select(c => new MsAddressCountryObject
    {
        ID = c.ID,
        CODE = c.CODE,
        COUNTRYNAME = c.COUNTRYNAME,
        MSADDRESSPROVINCEs = c.MSADDRESSPROVINCEs.Select(data => new MsAddressProvinceObject()
        {
            ID = data.ID,
            COUNTRYID = data.COUNTRYID,
            PROVINCENAME = data.PROVINCENAME,
            MSADDRESSCOUNTRY = new MsAddressCountryObject()
            {
                ID = data.MSADDRESSCOUNTRY.ID,
                CODE = data.MSADDRESSCOUNTRY.CODE,
                COUNTRYNAME = data.MSADDRESSCOUNTRY.COUNTRYNAME,
            },
            MSADDRESSDISTRICTs = data.MSADDRESSDISTRICTs.Select(dist => new MsAddressDistrictObject()
            {
                ID = dist.ID,
                PROVINCEID = dist.PROVINCEID,
                DISTRICTNAME = dist.DISTRICTNAME,
            })
        })
    });
}
```

For `MSADDRESSPROVINCE` I need to write the code like this.

```
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 4)]
public IQueryable<MsAddressProvinceObject> Get()
{
    return db.MSADDRESSPROVINCEs.Select(data => new MsAddressProvinceObject()
    {
        ID = data.ID,
        COUNTRYID = data.COUNTRYID,
        PROVINCENAME = data.PROVINCENAME,
        MSADDRESSCOUNTRY = new MsAddressCountryObject()
        {
            ID = data.MSADDRESSCOUNTRY.ID,
            CODE = data.MSADDRESSCOUNTRY.CODE,
            COUNTRYNAME = data.MSADDRESSCOUNTRY.COUNTRYNAME,
        },
        MSADDRESSDISTRICTs = data.MSADDRESSDISTRICTs.Select(dist => new MsAddressDistrictObject()
        {
            ID = dist.ID,
            PROVINCEID = dist.PROVINCEID,
            DISTRICTNAME = dist.DISTRICTNAME
        })
    });
}
```

That code works fast. But if I add/change/remove column, I have to modify the controller manually, one by one for all controller. For example, if I want to add geological coordinate in `MSADDRESSDISTRICT`, I have to change the code in Country Controller, Province Controller and District Controller.

So I decide to create extension method like this.

```
public static MsAddressCountryObject ToDTO(this MSADDRESSCOUNTRY data)
{
  return new MsAddressCountryObject()
  {
      ID = data.ID,
      CODE = data.CODE,
      COUNTRYNAME = data.COUNTRYNAME,
  };
}
public static IQueryable<MsAddressCountryObject  ToDTO(this IEnumerable<MSADDRESSCOUNTRY  datas)
{
  return datas.Select(country = 
  {
      var obj = country?.ToDTO();
      obj.MSADDRESSPROVINCEs = country.MSADDRESSPROVINCEs?.ToDTO();

      return obj;
  }).AsQueryable();
}

public static MsAddressProvinceObject ToDTO(this MSADDRESSPROVINCE data)
{
  return new MsAddressProvinceObject()
  {
      ID = data.ID,
      COUNTRYID = data.COUNTRYID,
      PROVINCENAME = data.PROVINCENAME,
      MSADDRESSCOUNTRY = data.MSADDRESSCOUNTRY?.ToDTO()
  };
}
public static IQueryable<MsAddressProvinceObject  ToDTO(this IEnumerable<MSADDRESSPROVINCE  datas)
{
  return datas.Select(province = 
  {
      var obj = province?.ToDTO();
      obj.MSADDRESSDISTRICTs = province.MSADDRESSDISTRICTs.ToDTO();

      return obj;
  }).AsQueryable();
}

public static MsAddressDistrictObject ToDTO(this MSADDRESSDISTRICT data)
{
  return new MsAddressDistrictObject()
  {
      ID = data.ID,
      PROVINCEID = data.PROVINCEID,
      DISTRICTNAME = data.DISTRICTNAME,
      MSADDRESSPROVINCE = data.MSADDRESSPROVINCE?.ToDTO()
  };
}
public static IQueryable<MsAddressDistrictObject  ToDTO(this IEnumerable<MSADDRESSDISTRICT  datas)
{
  return datas.Select(district = 
  {
      var obj = district?.ToDTO();
      obj.MSADDRESSSUBDISTRICTs = district.MSADDRESSSUBDISTRICTs?.ToDTO();

      return obj;
  }).AsQueryable();
}
```

And the controller just like this.

```
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 4)]
public IQueryable<MsAddressCountryObject  Get()
{
 return db.MSADDRESSCOUNTRies.ToDTO()
}
```

And that makes the performance really bad. I think the extension is making a lot of memory allocation or some thing that make the result not being delivered directly to the client.

My goal is to create the code easy to maintain, and the performance not drop significantly.
I have many relation in other table. I want the `$expand` works without write all parent/child `Select` statement manually and one by one.

I have try to not calling `ToDTO()` from all the extension method. The result is the performance is fast. But I lost all the relation or I need to write the parent/child `Select` statement for all method.

Any suggestion will help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't quote your code, quoting is for when you quote text from elsewhere. Code formatting is all that is required for code.

Comment: Sorry, I will revise it